# airbnb javascript style arrow-body-style rule, why parentheses out of braces?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions, airbnb-js-styleguide

According to [Airbnb Javascript Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#accessors), a pair of parentheses should be added to wrap the braces. But why?

```js
// good
[1, 2, 3].map((number, index) => ({
  [index]: number,
}));
```

Is there anything wrong if I code without those parentheses? I mean just return the object is easier to read.

```js
// anything wrong with this?
[1, 2, 3].map((number, index) => {
  return {[index]: number};
});
```

Comment: see how you are inside a function and not returning anything? This is the reason for the double.

Comment: Sorry I didn't edit the code correctly. Now it fixed.

Comment: Did you mean to link to https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#arrows--implicit-return? That tells you why it's preferred. Evidently the authors disagree with you about which is easier to read.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That rule explicitly lists OP's problem syntax as *good*. It's rather [this rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style).

Comment: @connexo yes, that's the underlying ESLint rule; I linked to where in the relevant style guide it's applied, which also says why.

Comment: Now I kind of understand the purpose of `()` here is to keep the literal object `{[index]: number}` being an expression.

Comment: Thx guys, I get the point now. But every time I saw code like this, it still takes a while for me to realize that ok `foo.map((number, index) => ({ [index]: number, }));` is a returned object literal wrapped as an expression.

Comment: They both do the same thing in the use case you've provided. Just a matter of style choice :) I use both for returning objects

Comment: yeah, both are right. In order to omit a `return`, they choose to add parentheses in parentheses.